# Bootstrap table generation how toget selected values from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I have created a bootstrap table that is populated from data, I want to be able to display the user checked values when the user clicks the "Get Selected" button

How do I get the selected name values?

here is my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/e3nk137y/12027/)  and code below

```
<table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-side-pagination="server"   data-click-to-select="true">
    <thead>
    <tr>
     <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
        <th data-field="name">Name</th>
        <th data-field="stargazers_count">Stars</th>
        <th data-field="forks_count">Forks</th>
        <th data-field="description">Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
      <fieldset>
        <input id="getSelected" type="button" value="Get Selected" />
        <input id="selectAll" type="button" value="Select All" />
        <input id="clear" type="button" value="Clear Selection" />
      </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do just a basic checking on when the row is `selected/unchecked`:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/12029/)

Here's updated JS:

```
var data = [
    {
        "name": "bootstrap-table",
        "stargazers_count": "526",
        "forks_count": "122",
        "description": "An extended Bootstrap table with radio, checkbox, sort, pagination, and other added features. (supports twitter bootstrap v2 and v3) "
    },
    {
        "name": "multiple-select",
        "stargazers_count": "288",
        "forks_count": "150",
        "description": "A jQuery plugin to select multiple elements with checkboxes :)"
    },
    {
        "name": "bootstrap-show-password",
        "stargazers_count": "32",
        "forks_count": "11",
        "description": "Show/hide password plugin for twitter bootstrap."
    },
    {
        "name": "blog",
        "stargazers_count": "13",
        "forks_count": "4",
        "description": "my blog"
    },
    {
        "name": "scutech-redmine",
        "stargazers_count": "6",
        "forks_count": "3",
        "description": "Redmine notification tools for chrome extension."
    }
];

$(function () {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable('load', {total: 5, rows: data});
    checkedRows = [];
    $('#table').on('check.bs.table', function (e, row) {
  checkedRows.push({name: row.name, stargazers_count: row.stargazers_count, forks_count: row.forks_count, description: row.description});
  console.log(checkedRows);
});

$('#table').on('uncheck.bs.table', function (e, row) {
  $.each(checkedRows, function(index, value) {
    if (value.name === row.name) {
      checkedRows.splice(index,1);
    }
  });
  console.log(checkedRows);
});

    $('#getSelected').click(function() {
    console.log(checkedRows);
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I clear the checked or when I use select all button to get all the checked values